# How to realloc some memory allocated using calloc?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, realloc, calloc

I've allocated a string with the *calloc* function:

```
//string1 and string2 previously declared
char *stringClone = calloc(strlen(string1) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

Now I want to do the same thing on *stringClone* with a different string. Doing:

```
stringClone = calloc(strlen(string2) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

I'm gonna have some memory leak, right? How should I use the *realloc* in this case?

Comment: Notice that if you want a clone of a string, there is a POSIX standard function `strdup` that does this in one call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `realloc()` to reallocate memory allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `aligned_alloc()` or `strdup()`. Note that if the reallocated block is larger than the original block returned by `calloc()`, the newly allocated portion will **not** be initialized to all bits zero.

Note however that the syntax for `realloc()` is not what you use: you must pass the pointer as the first argument and a single `size_t` for the new size. Furthermore, if a new block cannot be allocated, `NULL` is returned and the block is not freed, hence you should not store the return value directly to `stringClone`.

If you want to use `realloc()`, here is what you should do:

```c
//string1 and string2 previously declared
char *stringClone = calloc(strlen(string1) + 1, 1);
...
char *newp = realloc(stringClone, strlen(string2) + 1);
if (newp == NULL) {
    // deal with out of memory condition
    free(stringClone);
}
```

Since you do not seem to care that the contents of `stringClone` be preserved in the the reallocated block, you should probably simply write:

```c
//string1 and string2 previously declared
char *stringClone = calloc(strlen(string1) + 1, 1);
if (stringClone == NULL) {
    // deal with out of memory condition
    ...
}
strcpy(stringClone, string1);
...
free(stringClone);
stringClone = calloc(strlen(string2) + 1, 1);
if (stringClone == NULL) {
    // deal with out of memory condition
    ...
}
strcpy(stringClone, string2);
```

Note also that on POSIX compliant systems, there is a memory allocation function that is very useful for your use case: `strdup(s)` takes a pointer to a C string, allocates `strlen(s) + 1` bytes, copies the string to the allocated block and returns it:

```c
//string1 and string2 previously declared
char *stringClone = strdup(string1);
if (stringClone == NULL) {
    // deal with out of memory condition
    ...
}
...
free(stringClone);
stringClone = strdup(string2);
if (stringClone == NULL) {
    // deal with out of memory condition
    ...
}
```

Note also that casting the return value of `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` is unnecessary in C and considered bad style.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use `realloc` is that it keeps the original data intact. However, if I understand your use-case correctly, you intend to erase the original data. In that case, it is simpler and clearer to just write:

```
char *stringClone = calloc(strlen(string1) + 1, sizeof(char));
// check for calloc error
// use stringClone for string1
free(stringClone);
stringClone = calloc(strlen(string2) + 1, sizeof(char));
// check for calloc error
// use stringClone for string2
```

The error-checking is simpler for `calloc` than for `realloc`, since no temporary variable is needed. Also, this pattern makes it clear that the array contents for `string1` and `string2` are not related.